# filter object and return count in jasmine

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm new to jasmine-karma. so trying to figure out how to execute below scenario.

This works fine

```
describe("jasmine.objectContaining", function() {
  var foo;

  beforeEach(function() {
    foo = {
      a: 1,
      b: 2,
      bar: "baz"
    };
  });

  it("matches objects with the expect key/value pairs", function() {
    expect(foo).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining({
      bar: "baz"
    }));
  });
});
```

But now if I change object to array of objects it doesn't work.
So, how to filter from array of objects and return the count.

eg.

```
describe("jasmine.objectContaining", function() {
      var foo;

      beforeEach(function() {
        foo = [{
          a: 1,
          b: 2,
          bar: "baz"
        },
       {
          a: 1,
          b: 2,
          bar: "bdd"
        }

       ];
      });

      it("matches objects with the expect key/value pairs", function() {
        expect(foo).//find object(s) containing bar:"baz" and it should return count=1
        }));
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `jasmine.objectContaining` it can be implemented us:

```js
describe("array.filter returns entries", function() {
  var foo;

  beforeEach(function() {
    foo = [{
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        bar: "baz"
      },
      {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        bar: "bdd"
      }
    ];
  });

  it("matched by key/value", function() {
    expect(foo.filter(function(element) {
         return element.bar === 'baz'
    }).length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
```